# Using Firebase Realtime Database with SwiftUI List - Clearing a list

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm wondering what's the most effective way to clear a list's data that's presented in a View via an observable object? At the moment, everytime I reload the view the data gets duplicated (as we are checking the query for updates and parsing the responses). This is not the expected behaviour. The expected behaviour would be to only update the @Published property "if" the database indicates that a new notification has been received.

I know the culprit is the code within the .onAppear block - I'm just not sure architecturally how I might solve this. How could I use this listener while only parsing new data, not data that was previously parsed?

I attempted to clear the list .onAppear, but resulted in a crash indicated that I tried to delete a section while there were already 0 sections so that didn't work.

I've thought of possibly providing the Message object with a Static Unique ID to upload with the Message object when sending to Firebase (Or using the firebase key itself). That way I could use a set of dictionary objects using the unique ID to identify the object in the dictionary. This may help me avoid duplicate entries.

```
struct Updates: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataController = DataController()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {

            VStack {

                List {

                    ForEach(self.dataController.messages, id: \.id) { message in
                            Text(message.message)
                        }

                    }
                }.onAppear {

                    self.dataController.query.observe(.childAdded) { snapshot in
                        let data = JSON(snapshot.value as Any)

                        if let message = Message.parseFirebaseQuery(dataJSON: data){
                            self.dataController.messages.append(message)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class DataController: ObservableObject {

    @Published var query = ChatPathsAndReferences.refs.databaseMessages.queryLimited(toLast:100).queryOrdered(byChild: "date")
    @Published var messages = [Message]()

}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but I think the approach is going to be problematic. With Firebase, you don't need to add an observer in that fashion as Firebase does that for you. In other words, adding a .childAdded observer to a node will automatically send an event to the app when a child is added to that node. I think the way this code is, you're observing an observer. Also, you are correct in stating that .onAppear is the culprit as the code is re-run every time the view appears. I would suggest a custom initializer `init(_` to set up the firebase observer when the view is first instantiated.

Comment: Would this custom init execute once? Or would it continuously init each time I swap out of the view and back to the view?

Comment: It would execute when the view in instantiated. `.onAppear` executes whenever the view appears/disappears/appears etc.

Comment: @Karim, did you ever end up resolving this?

Comment: Hey @Xeaza, yes I did. I'll post an answer below to see the process.

Comment: Just added an answer @Xeaza. Just as a note, I haven't worked on this project in months so this may not be the best or most efficient way to do this. All I can promise you is that it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by adding an init block to my ObservableObject

```
class DataController: ObservableObject {

    @Published var query = ChatPathsAndReferences.refs.databaseMessages.queryLimited(toLast:100).queryOrdered(byChild: "date")
    @Published var messages = [Message]()

    init() {
       self.query.observe(.childAdded) { snapshot in
          let data = JSON(snapshot.value as Any)
       
          if let chatMessage = ChatMessage.parseFirebaseQuery(dataJSON: data){
             self.messages.append(chatMessage)
          }
       }
   }
}
```

So that now, when I create the view, the object initialises the observer in the data controller rather than the view.

```
struct Updates: View {
   // As you can see, we initialise the data controller which inits the observer. 
   // Since the messages in the data controller are @Published, 
   // we don't need to worry about checking for updates again in the view
    @ObservedObject var chatDataController: DataController = DataController()
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Color("Background")
                
                VStack {

                    // messages
                    List {
                        ForEach(self.chatDataController.messages, id: \.id) { message in
                                Text(message.message)
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! What I ended up finding in my own instance was I wasn't resetting my array within the completion block for the snapshot listener. Thus the old array + new items were being appended to the array of old items. ‍♂️ After getting that squared away my List correctly updated and displayed the right amount of items.

Comment: Do you have a specific need for resetting the Array each time? I figured the point of using an observable query with Firebase was so that you only had to listen for "updates", which is why I rethought my approach the first time around. Just curious about what you're trying to achieve, that's all! :)